# How do I effectively iterate over a large records and create a new list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have like 5000 records in the database and would like to iterate through them and then populate a new list how do I effectively achieve this? Below is my implementation I feel like it isn't effective.

**Example**

```
@documents = Document.all.reverse
files = []
@documents.each do |doc|
  reconciled = doc.primary_files.where(status: true).sum(:amount_credit)
  unreconciled = doc.primary_files.where(status: false).sum(:amount_credit)
  files.push({
    "id" => doc.id,
    "document_name" => doc.document_name,
    "records_count" => doc.primary_files.count,
    "total_collections" => doc.primary_files.sum(:amount_credit),
    "reconciled_sum" => reconciled,
    "unreconciled_sum" => unreconciled,
    "reconciliation_date" => doc.created_at
    })
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are loading all the documents in memory and doing a ton of N+1 queries.

Below are some ideas. The code is not tested at all.

So, if we are talking about more that 1k records then you can use [find_each](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods/find_each).

> Note: This method is only intended to use for batch processing of large amounts of records that wouldn’t fit in memory all at once. If you just need to loop over less than 1000 records, it’s probably better just to use the regular find methods.

Then, inside that loop you are doing N+1. It's best to create some associations and `eager_load` them.

```
# Example
has_many :reconciled, -> { where(status: true) }, class_name: 'PrimaryFile'
has_many :unreconciled, -> { where(status: false) }, class_name: 'PrimaryFile'
```

And finally (**untested !**):

```
files = []
Document.includes(:reconciled, :unreconciled).find_each do |doc|
  reconciled = doc.reconciled.map(&:amount_credit).sum // for eager loading
  unreconciled = doc.unreconciled.map(&:amount_credit).sum
  
  files.push({...})
end
```

You could also `eager_load` just `:primary_files` and get the `reconciled` and `unreconciled` by filtering the `doc.primary_files` array to get the sum. This way you eager_load just one relation instead of 3. It's up to you.

```
Document.includes(:primary_files).find_each do |doc|
  reconciled = doc.primary_files.select { |pf| pf.active }.sum(&:amount_credit)
  ...
end
```

Make sure when you run the loop you have NO N+1 queries.